# How to exclude some files from filename expansion mechanism in bash?

Tags: bash, filenames, wildcards, rm, bash-expansion

I have ubuntu file system directories in the root directory and I accidentally copied hundreds of files into root directory.

I intuitively tried to remove copied files by excluding file system like

```
rm -rf !{bin,sbin,usr,opt,lib,var,etc,srv,libx32,lib64,run,boot,proc,sys,dev} ./.
```

bu it doesn't work. What's the proper way to exclude some directories while deleting the whole?

EDIT: **Never try any of the commands here without knowing what to do!**

Comment: What shell are you using? Filename globbing is shell dependent when it comes to doing fancy stuff like that.

Comment: Not an answer, but I would use for example `mc`. Select everything with `*`, then deselect specific files with `-` or `Insert` key.

Comment: Can you explain what 'mc' is?

Comment: @Kusalananda it's `/bin/bash`

Comment: @MikeP: `mc` is Midnight Commander, a very useful imitation of Norton Commander. It runs in a terminal. (Both Midnight Commander and Norton Commander are examples of what is called an [orthodox file manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager#Orthodox_file_managers).)

Comment: You copied the files from somewhere... Do they still exist in that original place (ie not just in `/`)? If so you can use that to determine the files to be deleted. I can write an answer with this tonight

Comment: @roaima files got mixed, for example it copied subdirectories of `/etc` into `/` root

Comment: Never use `-f` with `rm` unless you absolutely have to!  O.o;

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you are using `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo rm -rf ./!(bin|sbin|usr|...)
```

I recommend to add `echo` at the beginning of the command line when you are running something what potentially can blow up the entire system. Remove it if you are happy with the result.

Note: The above command won't remove hidden files (those which name start by a dot). If you want to remove them as well then activate also `dotglob` option:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Comment: I used it to clean up the filesystem successfully. At first I tested it in a directory.  I also tried `rm -rf ./!(bin,sbin,..)` comma seperated, but it removes all directories.

Comment: What is that `!(...)` syntax? From the example I intuitively thought `ls ./!(*/)` would list only files, but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @giusti This syntax is extended pattern matching in filename expansion mechanism - you will find its description in the bash manual under Pathname Expansion chapter. It cannot be used to exclude files' types, only names, just like with star `*` or other globs.

Answer (score 12):

This command will show all non-directories in `/`:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Once you have made **absolutely** sure no files are there that you wish to keep, you can use:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

Safer, would be to move them elsewhere to ensure you aren't deleting something you want to preserve:

```
mkdir /root/preserve
find / -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -- "{}" /root/preserve/\;
```

If, in addition to files, you also have *directories* that you've added to the root of the filesystem, this *could* be automated by excluding the LSB directories from an automated `mv` or `rm`, but honestly, since we're dealing with purging things in the root of the filesystem, I would strongly suggest you consider doing it manually if at all feasible.

If this is not feasible, something like this could do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a excludes
for item in root sys 'lost+found' mnt home proc etc opt boot lib lib64 libx32 sbin media srv dev var usr bin tmp run; do
    excludes+=("$item")
done
if ! [[ -d /root/preserve ]]; then
    mkdir -p /root/preserve
fi
IFS="\n"
for item in find / -type d -maxdepth 1; do
    really=true
    for exclude in ${excludes[@]}; do
        if [[ "$exclude" == "${item#/}" ]]; then
            really=false
        fi
    done
    if [[ "true" == "$really" ]]; then
        mv -- "$item" /root/preserve/
    fi
done
```

Once you've passed the scream test (i. e. your system still runs and you are not screaming in anguish), you can remove the contents of `/root/preserve/`.

### Important note: Whatever you do, don't even think about running any permutation of `rm -fr [ANYTHING GOES HERE] /`.

Comment: your solution only deletes files but there are folders around too.

Comment: One too many times, I have heard shrieks of dismay from a poorly-aimed `rm`.  Like a script with `rm -fr $somepath/` with `somepath` uninitialized in it.  I could have gone further in expressing how grave this is, but opted to remain family friendly in my admonition.

Answer (score 3):

This should get the job done (though not in the same way as the OP asks):

```
ls -1 >1.txt
pico 1.txt
```

remove all files/directories you want to keep

```
xargs rm < 1.txt
```

If your files all have the same name format, date, or something else, then there are other methods.

I'd look at the inodes - and see if they are sequential via **ls -i |sort** and if they are, then the new files will have larger inodes. Then using the same type of process as above...

```
ls -iF1 | sort |cut -c10- | grep -vE "\/|\@" >i.txt   #This part removes entries that are not regular files, such as directories and links.  
pico i.txt
xargs rm < i.txt
```

in the cut command above, check your inodes list first to make sure it is the right amount.